# How to inject MANIFEST.MF into jar

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I was trying to, for debugging purposes, inject a (hacked) `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file into a `jar`.  I created a META-INF dir at the same level where the jar is and created my MANIFEST.MF file in it.  Then, per [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html):

```
jar uf myjar-with-dependencies.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

which executed without error but just wiped out the existing manifest without replacing it.  I know it because I ran:

```
jar tf myjar-with-dependencies.jar | grep MANIFEST
```

which, before the update, returned the found file in the jar but does not now after the update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"jar ufm" is what you're after. The m argument specifies that you're providing a manifest file.

```
jar ufm <yourJar> <yourManifest>
```

Otherwise it just treats it as a regular file which will end up getting stomped on when it generates the default manifest file.

Answer (score 3):

A Jar is just a zip file. You can open it up using any tool you would normally use to open a zip file and then just place your file inside of it where you want.

Comment: I was trying to be consistent and use the jar command to do it